# Public read access for S3 bucket not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**Updated screenshots :**

After receiving a notification from Amazon i searched to give only read access to public for my amazon S3 bucket and found many questions posted in stackoverflow but im still facing "access denied" message when trying to view the image.

Permission Overview [image]

Bucket Policy [image]

Access Control List [image]

Kindly let me know what im doing wrong here.

Thanks

-Vijay

Comment: Not sure why my images are not loaded while i followed the instructions from the editor

Comment: How did you configure "read only access to public"?

Comment: Did the notification from Amazon not include a documentation reference that can help you implement the change?

Comment: I have edited and updated the images, can someone look into it

Answer (score 0):

You assigned the wrong ACL. The one you assigned is at the bucket level which only controls the public read access of the *bucket ACL*, not the objects. Please follow [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/) guide to properly make objects public.

Comment: Yes, i followed this guide and updated the permission for the bucket. It was previously with full access to the public and i updated as above updated screenshots